# Selecting items in the Library with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I would like to get all the items named "itemX" (where X is a number) from the library in AS3. How can I do it? If it's not possible, is there a way to do something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var myItem:Class = getDefinitionByName("item" + i.toString()) as Class;
    addChild(new myItem);
}
```

for return :

```
var mc:MovieClip = new myItem();
return mc;
```

Comment: But what is the type of the object returned by getDefinitionByName? I tried to return that value, but I am having problems...

Comment: So how would I have to write a return function? I tried something like "public function ReturnTile ():MovieClip" that return myItem, but it complains with "Error 1034: cannot convert Tile_Test2$ to flash.display.MovieClip"...